# Auto-indentation not working for SAS language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, sas, indentation, vscode-extensions

I am trying the port my language extension for SAS for Atom https://atom.io/packages/language-sas to VScode. Everything works (syntaxes etc.) fine except auto-indentation.

I used `yo code` to create the template for my SAS language extension. I tried to use the same regular expressions I used in Atom but they do not seem to work. I also tried some very straightforward settings such as `"increaseIndentPattern": "^\s*(data|proc)\s*;$` but they do not seem to work either.

I currently have the following extensions installed: Python, Remote-SSH, TSLint, Visual Studio Intellicode, Tomorrow color theme.

Here are my `package.json` and `language-configuration.json`:

```
{
    "name": "sas-language",
    "displayName": "SAS",
    "description": "SAS language support for Visual Studio Code",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.36.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Programming Languages"
    ],
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": "sas",
                "aliases": [
                    "SAS",
                    "sas"
                ],
                "extensions": [
                    ".sas"
                ],
                "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
            }
        ],
        "grammars": [
            {
                "language": "sas",
                "scopeName": "source.sas",
                "path": "./syntaxes/language-sas.json"
            }
        ],
        "snippets": [
            {
                "language": "sas",
                "path": "./snippets/language-sas.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```
{
    "comments": {
        "lineComment": "*",
        "blockComment": ["/*", "*/"]
    },
    "brackets": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"]
    ],
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        {"open": "{", "close": "}"},
        {"open": "[", "close": "]"},
        {"open": "(", "close": ")"},
        {"open": "\"", "close": "\"", "notIn": ["string", "comment"]},
        {"open": "'", "close": "'", "notIn": ["string", "comment"]}
    ],
    "surroundingPairs": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"],
        ["\"", "\""],
        ["'", "'"]
    ],
    "indentationRules": {
        "increaseIndentPattern": "(?i:(\\bdo\\b(.(?!end;))*$|\\bbegingraph\\b(.(?!endgraph;))*$|^\\s*(proc|data|%macro)\\s+.*;\\s*$))",
        "decreaseIndentPattern": "(?i:(^\\s*(%?end|endgraph|endsas|run|quit|%mend)\\s*;))"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement complicated auto-indentation in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080997/how-to-implement-complicated-auto-indentation-in-vscode)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is a question regarding how to implement auto-indentation using the available mechanism. The other is regarding implement a more complicated one beyond what is offered directly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to your questions in these two issues: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74493 & https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27591#issuecomment-305175307.

The problem is in the ignore case modifier `(?i:)`. Apparently, it is an undocumented behavior. Remove the `(?i:)` modifier, and replace the regex_string with `{"pattern": regex_string; flags: "i"}`. So instead of:

```
"increaseIndentPattern": "(?i)...your regex here..."
```

Write:

```
"increaseIndentPattern": {"pattern": "(?i)...your regex here...", "flags": "i"}
```

And your indentation rules become:

```
"indentationRules": {
    "increaseIndentPattern": {"pattern": "\\bdo\\b(.(?!end;))*$|\\bbegingraph\\b(.(?!endgraph;))*$|^\\s*(proc|data|%macro)\\s+.*;\\s*$", "flags": "i"},
    "decreaseIndentPattern": {"pattern": "^\\s*(%?end|endgraph|endsas|run|quit|%mend|((proc|data)\\s+.*))\\s*;", "flags": "i"}

}
```