# How to implement complicated auto-indentation in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sas, indentation, vscode-extensions

I am working on a language extension for SAS for VScode. I previously worked on the SAS language extension for Atom (https://github.com/akanosora/language-sas) as well as Vim (part of the default Vim packages: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/sas.vim).

I am not very satisfied with the auto-indentation implementation in Atom and it seems that VScode provides more or less the same mechanism for auto-indentation.

The proper indentation for SAS code is quite tricky as the closing of a block is not always mandatory. A block in SAS typically starts with `data` or `proc` and ends with `run` or `quit`, and you can skip `run` to close it. For example, the following codes are both okay in SAS:

```
data female; 
    set total;
    where gender = 0;
run;

data male; 
    set total;
    where gender = 1;
run;
```

or

```
data female; 
    set total;
    where gender = 0;

data male; 
    set total;
    where gender = 1;
run;
```

So a proper auto-indentation for SAS requires more complicated rules than `increaseIndentPattern` and `decreaseIndentPattern` as they do not always pair with each other. I was able to implement that in Vim by comparing the closest `run` and `data` above the current line. If the `run` is more close to the current `data` line than the previous `data` line, then no indent is needed. Otherwise, indent the current `data` line. I want to know how feasible it is to implement that in VScode (maybe not relying on the `indentationRules` setting but use `vscode.languages.*` API?) I need some directions.

Comment: Even though SAS allows a DATA / PROC step to end without a run/quit, it's generally viewed as a poor coding style to make use of this feature.  If I were working on a language extension, I'd be fine with writing one that expects each step to be explicitly closed.

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced indentation, you could look into using a formatter alongside the regular expression based indentation rules. To add a custom formatter, your extension should implement [`DocumentRangeFormattingEditProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentRangeFormattingEditProvider) and then register the with VS Code by calling `registerDocumentRangeFormattingEditProvider`

Formatters must normally be invoked by the user. However users can also enable formatting as they type by setting `"editor.formatOnType": true`. For this case, your extension should also implement [`OnTypeFormattingEditProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#OnTypeFormattingEditProvider) and register the on-type formatter by calling  `registerOnTypeFormattingEditProvider`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `data` and `proc` keywords themselves to the `"decreaseIndentPattern"` rule. This way, these keywords will serve for both un-indenting the current line, and starting a new indentation block on the next line.

Consider this, for example:

```
"indentationRules": {
    "increaseIndentPattern": "^\\s*(proc|data)\\s+.*;\\s*$",
    "decreaseIndentPattern": "^\\s*(run|((proc|data)\\s+.*))\\s*;"
}
```