# VSCode redefining enter behavior in brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been trying to find how I could modify the behavior of pressing Enter in various brackets `()` `{}` `[]`. I've seen someone have this in a video (it was Sublime, but I didn't find how to do it there either).

When pressing enter now, the change is as follows:

```
{}
```

to

```
{
    [marker here]
}
```

What I would like to do is insert extra empty lines at the beginning and get this:

```
{

    [marker here]

}
```

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related question:
[How to implement complicated auto-indentation in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080997/how-to-implement-complicated-auto-indentation-in-vscode)

I tried to implement a similar `OnTypeFormattingEditProvider` that modifies the whitespace in a similar style as you want. It is easy to insert the whitespace you want in between the pair of brackets, but I did not figure out how to insert some before the cursor and some after the cursor. So instead of creating the insert edits and letting VS Code apply them, I opted for creating an `insertBeforeCursor` and `insertAfterCursor` edits, applying them using `workspace.applyEdit(...)` and subsequently moving the cursor using the `commands.executeCommand('cursorMove', { to: 'left', value: insertAfterCursorText.length } )` and returning `[]` out of the `provideOnTypeFormattingEdits` method.

See `applyAndMoveCursor` method in [this on-type formatter implementation](https://github.com/jan-dolejsi/vscode-pddl/blob/v2.14.4/client/src/formatting/PddlOnTypeFormatter.ts). I would be very happy if someone points out how to construct the edits and instruct VS Code whether the edit should/shouldn't move the cursor.

And do not forget to turn on the on-type formatting VS Code `editor.formatOnType` setting.